# How to initialize member objects that requires constructor parameters in derived classes?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, composition

I would like to include a `Composed` object in my `Base` class, and have different derived classes have different configurations of it. However the `Composed` class requires parameter in constructor, and I don't have control over its architecture.

The compiler is reporting an error because the parameter for `Composed` should be passed at the initialization of `Base` class. But I only want it to be initialized in derived classes. What should I do in this case?

```
class Base{
  public:
    Base(); //Error
  protected:
    Composed comp;
};
class Composed{
  public:
    Composed(int id):id(id);
  private:
    int id;
};
class Derived_1:public Base{
  public:
    Derived():comp(1234){};
};    
class Derived_2:public Base{
  public:
    Derived():comp(2345){};
};
```

Comment: Should `Base` even have a constructor? Could it be made pure virtual? If it has a `Composed` member but doesn't initialise it, is there any use of a `Base` object?

Comment: Makes good sense! Can you give a code example?

Comment: Of what? A non-existing constructor?

Comment: Sorry I'm forgetting everything about c++. If I remove the constructor of `Base`, the derived classes will complain " does not have any field named 'comp'"

Comment: Too little information, I'm afraid.

Comment: Just removing the constructor from the example code above, but fair enough.

Comment: The example code above doesn't even compile, with or without constructor. But yeah, neither of the derived classes have a `comp` member, so the error makes perfect sense.

Comment: Thanks for being informative

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to pass that parameter up to Base, and then hand it down to comp:

```
class Composed{
  public:
    Composed(int id):id(id);
  private:
    int id;
};
class Base{
  public:
    Base(int id):comp(id){}
  protected:
    Composed comp;
};
class Derived_1:public Base{
  public:
    Derived():Base(1234){};
};    
class Derived_2:public Base{
  public:
    Derived():Base(2345){};
};
```

Comment: Silly me! Forgot all the basics. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you constructed a `Base` object. How would it know what parameter to pass to `comp`'s constructor? The `Base` class is fundamentally flawed, that's why you have an error. It needs to know how to construct it's `Composed` member object.

You can add a default constructor for `Composed`, and then modify this object in `Derived_1` and `Derived_2`. Alternatively, as others suggested, you can make `Base`'s constructor take the parameters to construct `comp`. This sounds preferable to me, but it depends on your use case.

Remember that when you are constructing `Derived_1` or `Derived_2`, the `Base` class is the first thing that is created, before other member variables.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options.  The most straightforward is to pass the objects required to build Comp to the Base class constructor.

```
class Base{
  public:
    Base(int id):comp(id){}
protected:
    Composed comp;
};

class Derived_1:public Base{
  public:
    Derived():Base(1234){}
};    
class Derived_2:public Base{
  public:
    Derived():Base(2345){}
};
```

Another possibility is not to include Comp in the base class.  Put it in each derived class. You can add a pure virtual function to the Base class that returns Comp (or its address).

One more option is to store a pointer to Comp (perhaps a unique_ptr) and allocate it in the derived classes.